# Navigation bar hover color is not changing

Tags: html, css, web

```html
<div class="navbar-header"></div>
<div class="navbar-header"></div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse --></nav>
```

```css
================================================
7. Navigation
================================================
*/
.menu-bg {
    z-index: 999;
}
.menu-bg .basement-logo {
    padding-top: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    min-height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 30px 13px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #DC143C !important;
    color: #000;
}
.menu-bg .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    background-color: #DC143C !important;
    color: #000;
}
/*
```

I copy and pasted this from CSS code editor in file manager through my Cpanel account. I am trying to change the hover color to a red (#DC143C), but am failing miserably. I really appreciate your help so thanks in advance! I think it's obvious I am a novice and I am still trying to figure out the relationship between CSS, JavaScript, and HTML, so please have some patience. I've finally figured out basic networking, but this is a whole new ball game. Again, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: share the html code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Try to provide an MVCE example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You had forgot to add ul before li in css. use below code it works.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu-bg {
 z-index: 999;
}
.menu-bg .basement-logo {
 padding-top: 5px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default {
 background-color: inherit;
 border-color: inherit;
}
.navbar {
 border-radius: 0;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 border: none;
 z-index: 9;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 30px 13px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > ul > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > ul > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}
.menu-bg .navbar-default .navbar-nav ul li a {
 padding: 20px 10px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-nav" >
          <ul>
      <li style="height:50px;">  
                       <a href="#">dfsdgdsgs </li> </a>
      
   </div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I tried inserting, but I must have done something wrong...it did not work for me. Do I need to edit both the HTML and CSS code?

Comment: kindly Give me the html and css code.. you had tried

Answer (score 0):

Just simply insert the below css code to your CSS file. And I've provided the Codepen Link For you Check that
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dePmEY

```
.navbar-collapse ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
  background-color:#DC143C;
}
```

For further queries please provide your HTML code.

```css
.menu-bg {
 z-index: 999;
}
.menu-bg .basement-logo {
 padding-top: 5px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default {
 background-color: inherit;
 border-color: inherit;
}
.navbar {
 border-radius: 0;
 min-height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 border: none;
 z-index: 9;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0;
 height: auto;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 600;
 padding: 30px 13px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}
.menu-bg .navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
 padding: 20px 10px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
 background-color: #DC143C !important;
 color: #000;
}
.navbar-collapse ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
  background-color:#DC143C;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header"></div>

<div class="navbar-header"></div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
 <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ive posted an answer please check it and update me.For further modification pls provide your HTML code.Good Luck;)

Comment: I've updated the answer as per your requirement...Please check and be free to contact me.